# MLT framework windows build melt failed to load avformat

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mlt

I build mlt framework on windows following the official guide http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/WindowsBuild and the solution of [Error building MLT framework on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460171/error-building-mlt-framework-on-windows/29472194#29472194) for the errors.

But when I call the command `melt` it doesn't work correctly. (`melt noise` does work)

Using `melt -query "video_codecs"` I get `# No video codecs - failed to load avformat consumer`.

So it cannot load ffmpeg. Is there a problem with the compilation or is something related to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is a problem with the compilation. I doubt it is related to Windows itself. Shotcut provides a working copy of melt for Windows, which is built by cross-compiling and a massive script. The wiki page is not maintained; something like that is quickly out-of-date or very version-dependent.